# Automatically create Subfolders on SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have been trying to accomplish this for weeks now and end up hitting a wall.
I have a document library on SharePoint Online with the following (close enough) structure.

Clients

-> Schools

-->Client Name

--->Communications

--->Documentation

--->Projects

---->Project Name 1

---->Project Name 2

->Retail

-->Client Name

--->Communications

--->Documentation

--->Projects

---->Project Name 1

---->Project Name 2
... and so on.

Inside the "Projects" folder there is a set of folders as well.

Right now we have a Project template folder that we used to just copy/paste and rename when we had our file server, but now on SharePoint, the copy to process is way too many clicks to get it to that location.

What I am trying to accomplish is be able to create a new project folder and automatically create all the folders under it.

Appreciate the guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

My challenge was when creating the folder, it always wanted to create it inside the root of the document library and not the subfolder.

So I created 2 Content types for folders, one for clients and one for projects.
Used SharePoint Designer to create the workflow, but the trick here was to extract the URL from the current item, which is the folder being created, and remove the first x amount of characters from it which equals the SharePoint document library location. The remaining part of the string was the exact location where I wanted the subfolders to be created.
[image]

After that, I used that variable to create all other subfolders.